# Cannot install Windows application through Wine on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wine

Every time I install the program from the command line:

> wine ZaloSetup-24-1-1.exe

it always shows error:

> 0024:err:module:process_init L"C:\windows\system32\ZaloSetup-24-1-1.exe" not found

error message:

[image: error message]

Wine drive config:

[image: Wine drive config]

Answer (score 1):

The Zalo installer should launch fine on Ubuntu. Here are the steps to ensure that it is working:

1. Run `rm -rf ~/.wine` to delete your old wine data and apps
2. `sudo apt-get purge 'wine*' libwine 'wine*:i386'`
3. `sudo apt autopurge`
4. `sudo apt install wine wget`
5. `cd ~` To make sure you are in the correct folder
6. `wget https://res-download-pc-te-vnso-tt-2.zadn.vn/win/ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe` . This directly gets what https://zalo.me/pc would send you to
7. `ls ~/ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe` to check if the file is in the right folder
8. `wine ~/ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe`. Prefer the `./` (current directory) or `~/` (home directory) prefix while running .exe files to avoid confusing error messages like some .exe is not found in system32. You should see the following:

[image: zalo setup running]

Comment: why I type ''ls ~/Downloads/ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe'' it shows ''ls: cannot access '/home/guest/Downloads/ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe': No such file or directory''

Comment: Where do you save the "ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe" file? In your browser, click the three dots (chrome) or the three lines (firefox), and click "Downloads". The find the location or click the folder icon and right click properties to know. Then move it to the Downloads folder or follow the instructions with the new location

Comment: error: wine: cannot find L"./ZaloSetup-24.1.1.exe"

Comment: it is in the /home /guest /downloads

Comment: @HuyTấnNguyễn I added a `wget` command to ensure that the file is downloaded to the current directory. Does it work now?

Comment: Can you make it more clear which directory you want me to put the file

Comment: @HuyTấnNguyễn If you run my `wget` command, it will automatically put the file in the same directory that you are running the commands (I changed it so that it will put the file in your home directory)