Unable to install zalo through wine on ubuntu
I saw some tutorials that claims zalo can be installed through wine on ubuntu but none of them have posted welcome or login screen of the application. Normally we do not see fake answers on askubuntu so i decided to follow this guide and i realized it is fake Cannot install Windows application through Wine on Ubuntu 22.04 (@daniel-t)
I tried to install this app on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat) and Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular Oriole)
(a) Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)

sudo apt install wine wget
wget https://res-download-pc-te-vnso-tt-2.zadn.vn/win/ZaloSetup-24.8.5.exe (downloaded the latest version)
Run wine ZaloSetup-24.8.5.exe.

Advice-1: If you got error message, "it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it. multiarch needs to be enabled first". Please execute sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt install wine32
Advice-2: During installation, If you got error message in the terminal; "no NTLM support, expect problems. ntlm_auth was not found. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution". Please execute sudo apt install winbind
After the installation wizard appeared, i can choose a language and complete the installation.
zalo-setup-language-screenshot
zalo-installing-screenshot
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/store/.wine'
0054:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0054:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0054:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0054:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
004c:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
004c:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
004c:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
wine: configuration in L"/home/store/.wine" has been updated.
0134:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
0138:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
0178:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
017c:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
0180:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
0194:err:ole:create_server class {9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39} not registered
0194:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39} could be created for context 0x4

When Zalo application launches automatically. At this stage it fails and the wine debugger appears with an error message. "the program zalo.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconveniences".
zalo-launch-failed-screenshot
0260:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {7ab36653-1796-484b-bdfa-e74f1db7c1dc} not registered
0260:err:ole:create_server class {7ab36653-1796-484b-bdfa-e74f1db7c1dc} not registered
0260:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {7ab36653-1796-484b-bdfa-e74f1db7c1dc} could be created for context 0x5
01d4:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a} not registered
01d4:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a} not registered
01d4:err:ole:create_server class {aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a} not registered
01d4:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a} could be created for context 0x17
0260:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {7ab36653-1796-484b-bdfa-e74f1db7c1dc} not registered
0260:err:ole:create_server class {7ab36653-1796-484b-bdfa-e74f1db7c1dc} not registered
0260:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {7ab36653-1796-484b-bdfa-e74f1db7c1dc} could be created for context 0x5
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 21010059.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_update_window Failed to get a device context for window 0907A688.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 04010060.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_update_window Failed to get a device context for window 0907B210.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 05010065.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 05010069.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 0501006E.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 05010072.
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 05010077.
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread 360 at address 0579B2CF (thread 0360), starting debugger...
03b4:err:d3d:wined3d_context_gl_set_pixel_format wglSetPixelFormatWINE failed to set pixel format 1 on device context 0601007B.

This is the backtrace
0x0579b2cf zalo+0x539b2cf: int3
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info      Name (119 modules)
PE        400000- 89d6000       Export          zalo
ELF     5d0cd000-5d0d2000       Deferred        <wine-loader>
PE-Wine 71e70000-720b6000       Deferred        gdiplus
PE      720d0000-7210e000       Deferred        file-utils.node
PE-Wine 76f50000-76f71000       Deferred        powrprof
PE-Wine 76f90000-77010000       Deferred        netapi32
PE-Wine 77020000-7705b000       Deferred        msv1_0
PE-Wine 77070000-77099000       Deferred        kerberos
PE-Wine 770b0000-77155000       Deferred        uxtheme
PE-Wine 77170000-771bc000       Deferred        winex11
PE-Wine 771d0000-771ec000       Deferred        dhcpcsvc
PE-Wine 77200000-77241000       Deferred        jsproxy
PE-Wine 77260000-77361000       Deferred        winhttp
PE-Wine 77380000-77413000       Deferred        secur32
PE-Wine 77430000-778d7000       Deferred        comctl32
PE-Wine 778f0000-77914000       Deferred        compstui
PE-Wine 77930000-779d0000       Deferred        winspool
PE-Wine 779e0000-77c6d000       Deferred        dwrite
PE-Wine 77c80000-77ca6000       Deferred        userenv
PE-Wine 77cc0000-77cdb000       Deferred        version
PE-Wine 77cf0000-77d0e000       Deferred        nsi
PE-Wine 77d20000-77d60000       Deferred        dnsapi
PE-Wine 77d70000-77de8000       Deferred        iphlpapi
PE-Wine 77e00000-77e47000       Deferred        bcrypt
PE-Wine 77e60000-7815b000       Deferred        crypt32
PE-Wine 78170000-781fb000       Deferred        ws2_32
PE-Wine 78210000-78276000       Deferred        msacm32
PE-Wine 78290000-78402000       Deferred        winmm
PE-Wine 78420000-78435000       Deferred        msimg32
PE-Wine 78450000-786aa000       Deferred        dbghelp
PE-Wine 786c0000-78a7c000       Deferred        oleaut32
PE-Wine 78a90000-78b4c000       Deferred        oleacc
PE-Wine 78b60000-78ba1000       Deferred        coml2
PE-Wine 78bc0000-78dd1000       Deferred        rpcrt4
PE-Wine 78df0000-78f32000       Deferred        combase
PE-Wine 78f50000-7938d000       Deferred        ole32
PE-Wine 793a0000-794fb000       Deferred        uiautomationcore
PE      79510000-79899000       Deferred        ffmpeg
PE-Wine 798b0000-79913000       Deferred        imm32
PE-Wine 79930000-79971000       Deferred        shcore
PE-Wine 79990000-79a76000       Deferred        shlwapi
PE-Wine 79a90000-7a70e000       Deferred        shell32
PE-Wine 7a720000-7a757000       Deferred        win32u
PE-Wine 7a770000-7a9b0000       Deferred        gdi32
PE-Wine 7a9c0000-7accf000       Deferred        ucrtbase
PE-Wine 7ace0000-7ad6b000       Deferred        sechost
PE-Wine 7ad80000-7ae6c000       Deferred        advapi32
PE-Wine 7ae80000-7b119000       Deferred        msvcrt
PE-Wine 7b130000-7b15a000       Deferred        zlib1
PE-Wine 7b170000-7b637000       Deferred        user32
PE-Wine 7b650000-7bb7b000       Dwarf-4         kernelbase
PE-Wine 7bb90000-7bcf7000       Deferred        kernel32
PE-Wine 7bd10000-7bfee000       Deferred        ntdll
ELF     eee4d000-eee52000       Deferred        msv1_0.so
ELF     eee52000-eee57000       Deferred        netapi32.so
ELF     eee57000-eee82000       Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF     eee82000-eef3f000       Deferred        libzstd.so.1
ELF     eef3f000-eef75000       Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF     eef75000-eef9b000       Deferred        liblz4.so.1
ELF     eef9b000-ef0a8000       Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF     ef0a8000-ef0b5000       Deferred        libcap.so.2
ELF     ef0b5000-ef19c000       Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF     ef19c000-ef1ae000       Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF     ef1ae000-ef20e000       Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF     ef20e000-ef21d000       Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF     ef21d000-ef24d000       Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF     ef24d000-ef329000       Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF     ef329000-ef33f000       Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF     ef33f000-ef34e000       Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF     ef34e000-ef3a9000       Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF     ef3a9000-ef455000       Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF     ef456000-ef45e000       Deferred        kerberos.so
ELF     ef45e000-ef468000       Deferred        secur32.so
ELF     ef54f000-ef557000       Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF     ef557000-ef564000       Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF     ef564000-ef579000       Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF     ef579000-ef57e000       Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF     ef57e000-ef58d000       Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF     ef58d000-ef59b000       Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF     ef59b000-ef5a3000       Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF     ef5a3000-ef5a8000       Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF     ef5a8000-ef5ba000       Deferred        libmd.so.0
ELF     ef5ba000-ef5d0000       Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF     ef5d0000-ef5d7000       Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF     ef5d7000-ef5dc000       Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF     ef5dc000-ef60a000       Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF     ef60a000-ef75c000       Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF     ef75c000-ef772000       Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF     ef773000-ef77a000       Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF     ef77a000-ef77f000       Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF     ef77f000-ef785000       Deferred        winspool.so
ELF     ef785000-ef80f000       Deferred        winex11.so
ELF     ef80f000-ef81a000       Deferred        libffi.so.8
ELF     ef81a000-ef8ab000       Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF     ef8ab000-ef8f4000       Deferred        libhogweed.so.6
ELF     ef8f4000-ef947000       Deferred        libnettle.so.8
ELF     ef947000-ef95e000       Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF     ef95e000-efb0b000       Deferred        libunistring.so.5
ELF     efb0b000-efb3f000       Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF     efb3f000-efd0d000       Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF     efd0d000-eff4e000       Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF     eff50000-eff56000       Deferred        dwrite.so
ELF     eff56000-eff5b000       Deferred        dnsapi.so
ELF     eff5b000-eff61000       Deferred        crypt32.so
ELF     eff61000-eff6e000       Deferred        bcrypt.so
ELF     eff6e000-eff74000       Deferred        ws2_32.so
ELF     f0037000-f0063000       Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF     f0063000-f00b7000       Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF     f00b7000-f00da000       Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
ELF     f00da000-f0117000       Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF     f0117000-f0129000       Deferred        libbz2.so.1.0
ELF     f0129000-f0145000       Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF     f0145000-f0219000       Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF     f0219000-f0323000       Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF     f0336000-f04b9000       Deferred        win32u.so
ELF     f04b9000-f056e000       Export          ntdll.so
ELF     f056e000-f07aa000       Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF     f07ad000-f07bb000       Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
ELF     f07c5000-f07fa000       Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000030 services.exe
    00000034    0     
    00000038    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000003c    0     
    00000070    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000b0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000c4    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000fc    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    0000011c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000001ac    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000048 explorer.exe
    0000004c    0     
    00000058    0     
00000068 winedevice.exe
    0000006c    0     
    00000078    0     
    0000007c    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000080    0     
    00000084    0     
    00000088    0     
    000000d4    0     
    000000d8    0     
000000a8 svchost.exe
    000000ac    0     
    000000b4    0     
    000000b8    0     wine_sechost_service
000000bc plugplay.exe
    000000c0    0     
    000000c8    0     
    000000cc    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000d0    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000012c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000248    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    0000024c    0     wine_threadpool_worker
000000f4 winedevice.exe
    000000f8    0     
    00000100    0     
    00000104    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000108    0     
    0000010c    0     
    00000110    0     
    00000124    0     
    00000128    0     
000001a4 rpcss.exe
    000001a8    0     
    000001b0    0     
    000001b4    0     wine_sechost_service
    000001b8    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000001bc    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    00000264    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
000001d0 Zalo.exe
    000001d4    0     CrBrowserMain
    000001d8    0     BrokerEvent
    000001dc    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    000001e0    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000001e4   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    000001e8    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000001ec    0     Chrome_IOThread
    000001f0    0     MemoryInfra
    000001f4    0     
    000001f8    0     
    000001fc    0     
    00000200    0     
    00000204    0     
    00000208    0     
    0000020c    0     
    00000210    0     
    00000214   -2     ThreadPoolSingleThreadCOMSTASharedBackgroundBlocking0
    00000218    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    0000021c    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    00000220    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadCOMSTASharedForeground1
    00000224    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000228    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    0000022c    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking2
    00000230    0     CompositorTileWorker1
    0000023c    0     wine_sechost_device_notify
    00000240    0     VideoCaptureThread
    00000244    0     
    00000250    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadSharedForeground3
    0000025c    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000260    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadCOMSTASharedForegroundBlocking4
    00000268    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000026c   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    00000270    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000284    0     CacheThread_BlockFile
    000002dc   -2     ThreadPoolSingleThreadSharedBackgroundBlocking5
    00000464    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000468    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    0000046c    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000470    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000474    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000478    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    0000047c    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000480    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000484    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000514    0     wine_wininet_collect_connections
00000234 Zalo.exe
    00000238    1     CrGpuMain
    00000318    0     GpuWatchdog
    000003b4    0     wined3d_cs
    000003bc    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    000003c0    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000003c4   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    000003c8    1     Chrome_ChildIOThread
    000003d0    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    000003d4    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    000003d8    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000003dc    1     VizCompositorThread
    00000454   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    000004d0    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000004d4    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
00000254 Zalo.exe
    00000258    0     CrUtilityMain
    000002a0    0     BrokerEvent
    000002a4    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    000002a8    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000002ac   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    000002b0    0     Chrome_ChildIOThread
    000002b4    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000002b8    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000002bc    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    000002c0   -2     ThreadPoolSingleThreadCOMSTASharedBackgroundBlocking0
    000002c4    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    000002c8    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000002cc   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    000002d0    0     CacheThread_BlockFile
00000288 Zalo.exe
    0000028c    0     CrRendererMain
    000002e0    0     BrokerEvent
    000002e4    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    000002e8    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000002ec   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    000002f0    1     Chrome_ChildIOThread
    000002f4    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    000002f8    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    000002fc    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000300    0     GpuMemoryThread
    00000304    1     Compositor
    00000308    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadSharedForegroundBlocking0
    0000030c    0     CompositorTileWorker1
    00000310    0     CompositorTileWorker2
    00000314   -2     CompositorTileWorkerBackground
    0000031c    0     
    00000324    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000003e4    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000004d8    0     
    000004dc    0     
    000004e0    0     
    000004e4    0     
    000004e8    0     DedicatedWorker thread
    000004ec    0     DedicatedWorker thread
    000004f0    0     DedicatedWorker thread
00000290 Zalo.exe
    00000294    0     CrRendererMain
    00000320    0     BrokerEvent
    00000328    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    0000032c    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000330   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    00000334    1     Chrome_ChildIOThread
    00000338    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    0000033c    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    00000340    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000344    0     GpuMemoryThread
    0000034c    1     Compositor
    00000358    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadSharedForegroundBlocking0
    00000364    0     CompositorTileWorker1
    00000368    0     CompositorTileWorker2
    0000036c   -2     CompositorTileWorkerBackground
    00000370    0     
    00000374    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000003e0    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000488    0     
    0000048c    0     
    00000490    0     
    00000494    0     
00000298 ZaloCap.exe
    0000029c    0     
    00000348    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    00000350    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    000003b0    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000003b8    0     
    000003cc    0     
000002d4 Zalo.exe
    000002d8    0     CrRendererMain
    00000378    0     BrokerEvent
    0000037c    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    00000380    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000384   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    00000388    1     Chrome_ChildIOThread
    0000038c    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000390    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    00000394    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    00000398    0     GpuMemoryThread
    0000039c    1     Compositor
    000003a0    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadSharedForegroundBlocking0
    000003a4    0     CompositorTileWorker1
    000003a8    0     CompositorTileWorker2
    000003ac   -2     CompositorTileWorkerBackground
    0000045c    0     
    00000460    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000498    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0000035c (D) C:\users\store\AppData\Local\Programs\Zalo\Zalo-24.8.5\Zalo.exe
    00000360    0 <== CrRendererMain
    00000408    0     BrokerEvent
    0000040c    0     ThreadPoolServiceThread
    00000410    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000414   -2     ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
    00000418    1     Chrome_ChildIOThread
    0000041c    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    00000420    0     wine_threadpool_waitqueue
    00000424    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000428    0     GpuMemoryThread
    0000042c    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    00000430    1     Compositor
    00000434    0     ThreadPoolSingleThreadSharedForegroundBlocking0
    00000438    0     CompositorTileWorker1
    0000043c    0     CompositorTileWorker2
    00000440   -2     CompositorTileWorkerBackground
    00000458    0     
    000004a4    0     ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
    000004f4    0     
    000004f8    0     
    000004fc    0     
    00000500    0     
    00000518    0     
0000050c conhost.exe
    00000510    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-9.0 (Ubuntu 9.0~repack-4build3)
    Platform: x86_64 (guest: i386)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 6.8.0-41-generic

(b) Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular Oriole)
Note: If you have already read (a) and you do not have 24.10, you do not need to read this. You can use the details above to post an answer.
(b) -> https://pastebin.com/GpTGm5xU

Ubuntu 24.10 (oracular) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu oracular and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 3 October 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 10 October 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/oracular-oriole-release-schedule/36460  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu oracular you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

All packages used in your pastes are from oracular which isn't a supported product, only recently reaching beta.  If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues

@guiverc If it is a problem. i can reproduce this with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and post the result below. I know it'll be same. Please allow me some time.

This question is similar to: Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel this problem isn't similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/855474/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-different-from-other-instances-of-package. I guess you haven't read the entire post well. I'm trying to install a windows application through wine.
I found a similar question and already linked it above (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502715/cannot-install-windows-application-through-wine-on-ubuntu-22-04/) but OP haven't submit the question with good title, lack details and the community answer seems fake too. He have a very basic question and it doesn't describe my problem.

I got the link from your question here: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm19_1%3a19.1.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):  trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/llvm-19/lib/libLLVM.so.19.1', which is different from other instances of package libllvm19:i3 You can't install wine32 because of this error message.

@karel I have already explained how I solved that problem and installed wine32 on 24.10 successfully. It isn't the problem.
I found there's a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-19/+bug/2081839 and followed this workaround
sudo rm /usr/lib/llvm-19/lib/libLLVM.so.19.1
sudo apt --fix-broken install and finished wine32 installation.

If your actual question is only related to step 10, please remove all the other narrative.

@organic-marble thank you. removed.

@guiverc In response to your question, I reproduced this with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and updated the question. You can check it.

@karel If you can't find the content you mentioned above, please check part (b). :)
